# Powershell -> find/replace in Excel -> look for a string in one cell and change the string in another cell

Tags: excel, powershell, search, replace

I would like to search for a string in a column. If it finds that string, I would like the script to replace the string in another cell - same row, different column. So my columns are like this...

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yOKry.png)

I want to search for "Hours" or "Hrs" in column "Unit Type" and when it finds it, I want to change the "Job ID" in that same row to 3289. Here's what I got so far and nothing seems to happen. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
$excelFile = "C:\do\BEFORE.xls"
$objExcel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$WorkBook = $objExcel.Workbooks.Open($excelFile)
$worksheet = $WorkBook.sheets.item("Sheet1")
$rowCount = $worksheet.usedrange.rows.count

Select-Object "Acct", "Customer_Name", "Invoice","Inv_Date","Cost_ID","Job_ID","Description","Hours", "Quantity", "Price", "Unit_Type", "Amount"

foreach ($row in $excelFile) {
    if ($row.Unit_Type -eq "Hours") {
        $row.Job_ID = "3289"
    }
}

$WorkBook.Save()
$WorkBook.Close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Select-Object` command is not doing anything as you're not providing it any data. Though that doesn't matter much since you're dealing with an excel com object. You'll need to specify which column you're checking and I find it's easiest to use a for loop. We will start on row 2 since the first row is the headers. Based on your example the Unit Type column is 6 and the Job ID column is 1. You also wanted to check for either hours or hrs so a regex match would be an appropriate approach.

```
$excelFile = "C:\do\BEFORE.xls"
$objExcel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$WorkBook = $objExcel.Workbooks.Open($excelFile)
$worksheet = $WorkBook.sheets.item("Sheet1")
$rowCount = $worksheet.usedrange.rows.count

$unittypecolumn = 6
$jobidcolumn = 1

for($i = 2; $i -le $rowCount; $i++)
{
    if($worksheet.Cells($i,$unittypecolumn).Value2 -match "hours|hrs")
    {
        $worksheet.Cells($i,$jobidcolumn).Value2 = "3289"
    }
}

$WorkBook.Save()
$WorkBook.Close()
```